# Custom character encoding in C

Tags: c, character-encoding

I have a specific usage case where I need to have strings represented with a custom character encoding specific to this usage case. Fonts, etc. are already taken care of, but I would like to be able to type something like:

```
static char *test= "Test string";
```

and have it be equivalent to a bytestring of:

```
CE D9 E7 E8 00 E7 E8 E6 DD E2 DB FF
```

which is not an encoding used anywhere else. Is there a way to tell GCC to use this execution encoding when strings are written in the source?

Comment: In C++ you might use custom `constexpr` string literal suffix.

Comment: Using C, not C++, sorry.

Comment: You represent space as the null character? This is not going to work.

Comment: You have to develop all support functions (strlen, strcpy and so on) for your encoding. There isn't standard function that uses 0x00 as space. 0x00 is reserved to null-terminator in C-Strings

Comment: @SFO Not in the source file, I only would need it to be as such once the code is compiled and the program is executing. Confusing, but such is the nature of its usage.

Comment: @LPs That's covered already, I've already been representing the strings as bytestrings but I would prefer to have the compiler interpret the strings automatically for me instead if at all possible.

Comment: Maybe you could isolate your string literals to a specific section. Then you could convert standard representation with an external tool after gcc complete its job.

Comment: @LPs That could conceivably work, might take a bit of finagling. Thanks!

Comment: @DiegoA. May I ask you why are you trying to use a custom character encoding? If this is some attempt of doing cryptography you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @Havenard This code is actually being compiled for and inserted into a preexisting video game ROM, which has its own definitions of character encodings. It's just a really odd usage case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to build your own `iconv` package that supports your encoding. [Here's how](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/libiconv.git/tree/NOTES), scroll down to "How do I add a new character set?".

Then you can cause `gcc` to use your custom `iconv` by setting `LD_PRELOAD` or whatever.

Then use `-fexec-charset` and `-fwide-exec-charset` gcc options.

You may also need to build your own libc. You might be able to get away with just recompiling glibc with the options above. Or not, depending on how well iconv and glibc can cope with a "null" terminator which is not encoded as a numeric zero. The C language requires that `'\0' == 0`, but in your encoding 0 seems to encode space.

Comment: never look at that before. Is it possible to redefine null-terminator value building a specific `iconv`?

Comment: I have no clue how to integrate this with my odd GCC toolkit but this certainly seems like a step in the right direction. Thank you!